# Rails 4 + Globalize + Activeadmin + activeadmin-globalize , activeadmin-translate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin, globalize

**The block:**

```
form do |f| | f |
    f.translate_inputs of | t |
      t.input : title
      t.input : text
      t.input : locale , as: : hidden
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Always shows the last field , I believe the problem is the gem ' activeadmin -translate ' github ' rbatllet / activeadmin -translate ' .

**ADMIN/POST.RB**

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Post do    # if you are using Rails 4 or Strong
 Parameters:   permit_params :title, :text, translations_attributes:
 [:locale, :title, :text, :id]


   index do
     # ...
     translation_status
     # ...
     #default_actions   end

   form do |f|
     f.translate_inputs do |t|
       t.input :title
       t.input :text

       t.input :locale, as: :hidden
     end
     f.actions   end end
```

models/post.rb

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

active_admin_translates :title, :text     do
        #validates_presence_of :title
end

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations
 end
```

Comment: You should organizer your code for starters. For example, `form do |f| | f | ` is supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in a `inputs do`

try

```
   form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
     f.translate_inputs do |t|
       t.input :title
       t.input :text

       t.input :locale, as: :hidden
     end
   end
     f.actions
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using this gem: https://github.com/unmantained-activeadmin-plugins/activeadmin-globalize. Be aware that on the readme of this gem it's noted:

> Sorry, but I no longer work on ActiveAdmin often enough to justify
>   mantaining this gem.